# Tomcat default value for socket.soKeepAlive

Tags: sockets, tomcat, jvm

I am trying to debug an issue related to keep-alives/connection resets and found that [tomcat documentation says](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html):

> **socket.soKeepAlive**:
>
> (bool)Boolean value for the socket's keep alive setting (SO_KEEPALIVE). JVM default used > if not set.

This is not set by the application I am debugging. Is there a way to figure out the default the jvm is using? (For instance by inspecting a system property?)

I cannot test out the behavior by inspecting the actual keep alive behavior since I don't have access to the VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering on my own based on more research and experimentation.

**Default value of `socket.soKeepAlive`**: From the JVM docs for [SocketOptions.SO_KEEPALIVE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/StandardSocketOptions.html#SO_KEEPALIVE):

> The initial value of this socket option is FALSE. The socket option may be enabled or disabled at any time.

Also to note:

> When the SO_KEEPALIVE option is enabled the operating system may use a keep-alive mechanism to periodically probe the other end of a connection

From what I understood, this would mean **tomcat would not probe clients** to check if an established connection is active **by default**

**Default Value of `keepAliveTimeout`**: The default value is to use the value that has been set for the connectionTimeout attribute

In my case this was not being reflected. `connectionTimeout` was set to 10 seconds, but still tomcat responses had keep alive headers set to only 5 seconds.

However, I found that the application authors also set an attribute called `socket.soTimeout` to 5 seconds which tomcat describes as:

> This is equivalent to standard attribute **connectionTimeout**.

I found that when both `conncetionTimeout` and `socket.soTimeout` are set, `socket.soTimeout` takes precedence since changing the `socket.soTimeout` value caused the values returned by keep alive headers to change accordingly.

Comment: You are confusing TCP keepalive with HTTP keepalive. TCP keepalive is (a) poorly named; (b) set by `socket.soKeepAlive`; and (c) causes the OS to send keepalive packets to see if the peer responds. The default timeout for that is 2 hours. HTTP Keep-alive is about how long the server will keep the connection open waiting for another request. It is specified via `keepAliveTimeout` and implemented via `socket.soTimeout`, as is `socket.connectionTimeout`, although the latter two aren't the same thing, as adequately described in your link.

Comment: Yes, I was initially, mostly due to the name conflicts